# CORBA (orbd) networking configuration?

Tags: java, corba

I'm just starting working with CORBA.  Basically, I'm having to implement a Java application that acts as a CORBA client.

At this point, I'm mainly using the Sun JDK (JDK6) tools, including idlj.exe (to compile the IDL that I was given) and orbd.exe (for testing my code), and so far, I've been able to use the idlj and the IDL to create the Java classes, and I also wrote a test server app and test client app that are both now working (I had to write the small server app so that I could test my client app).

As I said above, I'm using orbd.exe as the ORB for my testing.

Initially, I had orbd.exe, my Java server app, and my Java client app, all running on the same machine, and that worked.

I've also tested in a more distributed configuration, where I ran orbd.exe and my Java server app on another machine (testxp), and my Java client app on a separate machine, and that works.

My question is as follows:  A lot of the documents, web pages, etc. that I've seen re. CORBA have diagrams showing two ORBs, e.g., a server app and an ORB on one machine, and a client app and another/2nd ORB running on another/2nd machine, with the two ORBs communicating with each other:

client app ==> ORB1 ----> ORB2 ==> server app

whereas, in my testing so far, using orbd.exe as the ORB, I only have been using one ORB.

So, I was wondering how can I configure a test configuration where there are two ORBs as described above?

Can I do that using orbd.exe, or does orbd.exe not work in that type of configuration?

Also, if that can be done using orbd.exe, how do I do that?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

CORBA is an architecture and infrastructure to communicate application in a network. And ORB is the component that serialize (marshal) and deserialize (unmarshal) the calls to IIOP. With CORBA, you can write a code in C# (using [IIOP.NET](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/)) and communicate with a server in Java.

So, you are right, the communication is made between ORBs.

|client app| <==> ORB1 <--(IIOP)--> ORB2 <==> |server app|

ORBD is an ORB with a Naming Server. It is ideal that you have only one Name Service, you can read about name service [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13211_01/wle/naming/over.htm).

Finally, you have many ways to start comunication between ORBs. (a) activate servant in the POA and call method *poa.object_to_string(servant)*, write the string in a file then read it in the client using *poa.string_to_object(fileAsString)*. (b) define server host and port and use corbaloc. (c) subscribe in a name server (best option).

Try to use three process in your test. Name Server, Client, Server.

PS: I like JacORB then JDK Orb

EDIT:
Adding some code to help:

```
orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, props);
org.omg.CORBA.Object obj = this.orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");
this.rootPOA = POAHelper.narrow(obj);
POAManager manager = this.rootPOA.the_POAManager();
manager.activate();
```